# Fastest way to read/write an array from/to a file?

Tags: java, arrays, file, io

I know there were several similar threads here and on the net but I seem to be doing something wrong, I guess. My task is easy - write (and later read) a big array of integers (int [] or ArrayList or what you think is best) to a file. The faster the better. My concrete array has about 4.5M integers in it and currently the times are for example (in ms):

- Generating trie: 14851.13071
- Generating array: 2237.4661619999997
- Saving array: 89250.167617
- Loading array: 114908.08185799999

This is unacceptable and I guess the times should be much lower. What am I doing wrong? I don't need the fastest method on earth but getting these times to about 5 - 15 seconds (less is welcome but not mandatory) is my goal.

My current code:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();

Node trie = dawg.generateTrie("dict.txt");
long afterGeneratingTrie = System.nanoTime();
ArrayList<Integer> array = dawg.generateArray(trie);
long afterGeneratingArray = System.nanoTime();

try
{
    new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.txt")).writeObject(array);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Logger.getLogger(DawgTester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
}
long afterSavingArray = System.nanoTime();

ArrayList<Integer> read = new ArrayList<Integer>();
try
{
    read = (ArrayList)new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("test.txt")).readObject();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Logger.getLogger(DawgTester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
}
long afterLoadingArray = System.nanoTime();

System.out.println("Generating trie: " + 0.000001 * (afterGeneratingTrie - start));
System.out.println("Generating array: " + 0.000001 * (afterGeneratingArray - afterGeneratingTrie));
System.out.println("Saving array: " + 0.000001 * (afterSavingArray - afterGeneratingArray));
System.out.println("Loading array: " + 0.000001 * (afterLoadingArray - afterSavingArray));
```

Comment: I know but I don't know whether I should array or ArrayList.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use java Serialization.  it is very powerful and robust, but not particularly speedy (or compact).  use a simple `DataOutputStream` and call `writeInt()`.  (make sure you use a `BufferedOutputStream` between `DataOutputStream` and `FileOutputStream`).

if you want to pre-size your array on read, write your first int as the array length.

Comment: 1. Should I use int [] or ArrayList<Integer>? Or it doesn't matter?   ---    2. Could you provide some code samples? I'm afraid that I might mix something up and end up with slow/broken code anyway.

Comment: @NPS - if you need to store the data in some sort of list structure, an int[] would be the fastest/most memory efficient.  however, if you are ultimately using another data structure, it would probably be faster to just use that directly.

Comment: 1. I need anything that works like an array, i.e. takes one (possibley small) block of memory and has index-access. --- 2. I think I managed to use your advice but tell me one more thing - should I call writeInt() on every array element separately, i.e. call it 4.5M times?

Comment: @NPS - yes, you would call writeInt() for each array element (and optionally first for the array length).

Comment: Thank you, that shrank my loading/saving times drastically, now they're both about 0.25 - 0.3 sec. I'm surprised though - I thought 1 operation saving whole block would be faster than 4.5M operations saving every element but I guess in my case the former just wasn't a single block and 1 operation. :P

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following is probably a fairly fast option. You should also use an actual array `int[]` rather a `ArrayList<Integer>` if you're concern is reducing overhead.

```
final Path path = Paths.get("dict.txt");
...
final int[] rsl = dawg.generateArray(trie);
final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(rsl.length << 2);

final IntBuffer buf_i = buf.asIntBuffer().put(rsl).flip();
try (final WritableByteChannel out = Files.newByteChannel(path,
    StandardOpenOptions.WRITE, StandardOpenOptions.TRUNCATE_EXISTING)) {
  do {
    out.write(buf);
  } while (buf.hasRemaining());
}

buf.clear();
try (final ReadableByteChannel in = Files.newByteChannel(path,
    StandardOpenOptions.READ)) {
  do {
    in.read(buf);
  } while (buf.hasRemaining());
}
buf_i.clear();
buf_i.get(rsl);
```